# use ord function in haskell is not is scope

Tags: haskell

Pretty simple, I want to convert a character to integer using the function `ord`, however it is not loaded automatically in the prelude because it says:

```
*Main> ord 'a'

<interactive>:55:1:
Not in scope: ‘ord’
Perhaps you meant one of these:
  ‘odd’ (imported from Prelude), ‘or’ (imported from Prelude)
```

How, for heaven's sake, I can use it??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to import `Data.Char` first:

```
import Data.Char
```

Comment: Is this something equivalent of a pythonic statement `from Data import Char`?

Comment: @user2820579 - No it's more like `from Data.Char import *`. If you just want to import `ord` you can use `import Data.Char (ord)`.

Comment: @user2820579, for the python semantics, use `import qualified Data.Char as Char`